# How to automate stackdriver monitoring? Why stackdriver apis are used for?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google, google-kubernetes-engine, google-stackdriver

How can I create new stack driver chart for any VM or cluster or pods created in Stackdriver automatically? Is there any way to achieve stackdriver charts as soon as any resource mentioned above is created in GCP  environment? What are the stackdriver apis are used for ?

Answer (score 0):

In can not be done automatically in [stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/) you need to access you [Workspace](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/) after creating it, and [ADD Chart](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/) in your Dashboard.

Stackdriver monitoring API gives you access to over [900 Monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics) from Google Cloud Platform and Amazon Web Services. You can create your own custom metrics and can organize your cloud resources using groups,it's uses filters to select metrics, to fetch time-series data, and to collect monitored resources into groups.